# How to solve this kind of ternary operation

Tags: c#, linq

roleList is a list as a string type  which contains roles

```
List<string> designationlistForQuery = new List<string>();
  roleList.ForEach(r =>
       {
  !r.Equals(shortDesignation) ?   designationlistForQuery.Add(r) : delegate{};


      });
```

but compilers shows me : there is no implicit conversion between 'void' and 'anonymous method'
how can i solve this please someone help me .

Comment: What for you are using `delegate{}`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? This code makes no sense at all...

Comment: delegate{} use for return as void

Comment: Do you perchance mean `delegate()`?

Comment: @user1427614: There is no such thing as "return as void". Void means *no return value*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : I know void means no return value. but in these scenario can you solve using ternary operator ? i need only ternary operator, i know i can solve this like roleList.ForEach(r=> { if(!r.Equals(shorDesignation)){designationlistQuery.Add(r);}}

Comment: @user1427614 you can't use ternary operator with `void`. End of story

Comment: @Joe Enos already solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want, but this is atrocious syntax:

```
roleList.ForEach(r =>
    {
       (!r.Equals(shortDesignation) ? (Action) (() => designationlistForQuery.Add(r)) : (Action) (() => { }))();
    }
);
```

If you want it nice and short, here's an option:

```
designationlistForQuery.AddRange(roleList.Where(x => !x.Equals(shortDesignation)));
```

There are a dozen other ways to write it as well, some clearer than others - but I'd definitely avoid your delegate approach.

Comment: thanks a lot.I give you a +1 for this.

Comment: @user1427614, please don't use this in real code... This is about the ugliest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use simple `foreach` operator:

```
foreach(var role in roleList)
  if (role.Equals(shortDesignation))
      designationlistForQuery.Add(role);
```

Or

```
var rolesToAdd = roleList.Where(r => r.Equals(shortDesignation));

foreach(var role in rolesToAdd)
    designationlistForQuery.Add(role);
```

Comment: i can do like this i know but i want to use ternary operator. can you tell how to do this please

Comment: @user1427614 I can't until you explain your intent clearly. Thus `designationlistForQuery.Add` returns `void` and `delegate{}` is meaningless, then ternary operator is not an option. foreach is what you actually should use to execute `designationlistForQuery.Add` on each role matching your condition

Comment: Why? who cares if it's ternary or not? Ternary is just a shorthand

Comment: my intention to practise ternary operation in situation like this.I have solve many times like this way that you already told.But i can't help me out of this.if you can please give a solution.

Comment: there is no reason for you to use the conditional operator in this circumstance. this is bad practise. this is not how it is meant to be used.

Comment: @user1427614 *'my intention to practice ternary operation in situation like this'* - ternary operator cannot be used in situations like this. So, just stop practicing and use this operator in situations which require selection of *return value* from two possible *values*. Suggested reading: [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: @user1427614 If your intention is to learn, then you have indeed learned something useful: **ternaries are not appropriate in this situation!**

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (that's its name, not *ternary operator*) here. You're *performing an action* on each item, not returning a value; the conditional operator is used to return a value, so using it with void operands makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange to use `?:` with methods that return no value, but if you really need it - wrap into lambda that returns a fake value like:

```
Func<int> action = condition ?
    ()=> { VoidMethod(); return 42;} :
    (Func<int>)(()=>42);
```

Note: you need cast at least on side to concrete type like `(Func<int>)` in this case as C# can't determine good common type with just 2 lambdas.